# Monthly time series plot with years on x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, charts, time-series, axis-labels

I'd really appreciate any help to create a time series plot in R. I'm a total newbie and my programming knowledge is really limited. I just need to create this one graph and it has to be done in R, not Excel.

I have the following monthly data:

```
Time   HML
200207 6.28 
200208 3.44
200209 8.03
...
201412 1.47
```

I have a really hard time to understand how time variable is defined or how it should be converted.

Now I need to plot it so on the X-axis there are only years visible i.e. 2002, 2003, 2004, (...), 2014.

Here's my code:

```
plot(HML, type="l", lwd=2, col="red", ylab= "% return")
abline(h = 0, col = "black", lty = "solid")
```

Any help much appreciated.

Best regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a time series object! (using `ts()`)

Then plot, I guess R will show only years on X-axis automatically!

```
#make Time to time series object
a<-ts(rnorm(150),start=c(2002,7),freq=12);a
plot(a, type="l", lwd=2, col="red", ylab= "% return",xlim=c(2002,2014),axes=F)
axis(1,at=2002:2014,labels=2002:2014);axis(2);box()
```

Explain code:

1. start in `ts()` means the times of the first observation
2. freq means the number of observations per unit of time.
3. We can control the range of X-axis by `xlim`!
4. I don't know how to show all years by code easily,but a stupid method I always use is create one by myself. Hence, adding `axes=F` in plot means do not show the default axis. Then, create what axis I hoped by `axis()` and `label` show all years!
5. Finally, make a box around your picture!
   [image]

BTW You can find more details by typing `?ts` in R !

Comment: Thanks, Lin! Unfortunately, not all years are visible, only 2004, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2014. Is there any way to manually change this and e.g. state that 2002 is the starting point on the x-axis?

Answer (score 1):

Read in the data using `read.zoo` and class `"yearmon"` (which represents a year and month) for the index.  Then plot it using `xaxt="n"` to suppress the axis.  Finally produce the axis yourself using `axis` to force years only:

```
Lines <- "Time   HML
200207 6.28 
200208 3.44
200209 8.03
201412 1.47"

library(zoo)
HML <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%Y%m",
 colClasses = c("character", NA))

plot(HML, xaxt = "n", type = "o", xlab = "Year")
rng <- range(floor(time(HML)))
axis(1, rng[1]:rng[2])
```

Continued after image.

[image]

**Note 1:** If you already have the data as a data frame `DF`

```
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

then you could replace the `read.zoo` statement with:

```
HML <- zoo(DF$HML, as.yearmon(as.character(DF$Time), "%Y%m"))
```

**Note 2:** I can't tell whether the actual data has data for every month from the first to the last but the above work even if not.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this... Here is one of them. We'll be using hypothetical data spanning from 2002-01 to 2012-12 (having gaps doesn't matter in this case). Note that we've used the 1st of each month to have a complete date, easily recognizable by the function `as.POSIXct` which will convert strings to time objects.

```
Time <- c("2002-01-01", "2002-02-01", "2003-03-01", "2003-04-01", 
          "2004-05-01", "2004-06-01", "2005-07-01", "2005-08-01", 
          "2006-09-01", "2006-10-01", "2006-11-01", "2008-01-01", 
          "2008-02-01", "2009-02-01", "2009-03-01", "2010-04-01", 
          "2010-05-01", "2010-06-01", "2011-07-01", "2011-08-01", 
          "2012-09-01", "2012-10-01", "2012-11-01", "2012-12-01")

HML <- rnorm(n = 24, mean = 6, sd = 2)

dat <- data.frame(Time=as.POSIXct(Time), HML)
rm(Time, HML)
```

And then use the `plot` function:

```
plot(HML ~ Time, type="l", col="red", lwd=2, ylab= "% return", data=dat)
```

[image: HML as a function of time]

Answer (score 1):

Using `ggplot2` would give you a lot of options. The `autoplot` function accepts and plots `zoo` objects.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

hml_ts <-
  ts(rnorm(150),start=c(2002,7),freq=12)

hml_zoo <-
  as.zoo(hml_ts)

gg <-
  hml_zoo %>%
    autoplot() + 
    xlim(c(2002, end(hml_zoo)))

gg
```